# Is it possible to make a car with this kind of functional axle?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, collision

I was trying to make a car and make the axle "work" mechanically.
My idea was to make an axle with a flat end and a wheel that would enclose around it like this:

[image]

Only, when I give these objects rigid body properties, this is what happens:

[image]

I've played with a lot of the settings and the result is never really functional. So this makes me wonder if I'm trying to use Blender in a way it's not intended to be used...

If making these parts is not possible, I would love to know how to animate the wheels of a vehicle in motion (but maybe that's for another question...)

[image]

Comment: I don't exactly follow what you are trying  to do. In the real world the axel and tire hub would be bolted together.... but I can tell you this:  **always apply your transformations**... (Ctrl+A) otherwise the scale and rotation of your objects will adversly affect physics simulations... http://i.stack.imgur.com/vSGt5.gif

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: If the objects are joined together then you have this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wc3Ql.gif

Comment: the proper way to rig a wheel with rigid body physics is to use a hinge constraint to hold the wheel to the axle via an empty.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood is there a link somewhere? Maybe another question?

Comment: @cegaton : trying to make the wheel move but not the axle (attached to car)

Comment: Movement will require a motor constraint on top of the hinge constraints, unless you rely on gravity alone.

Comment: This guy has a few tutorials on rigging a car using rigid body physics in the BGE. He uses some python scripting, but other than that, the only drawback is that it's for the BGE only. Rigid body physics are a little different (more complex) outside of the game engine. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5gNwGp8Zz0

Comment: @AnthonyForwood ok thanks! I'd rather use Cycles. I'll look for a similar question and try both... Using gravity could be fun though...

Comment: Cycles is the same as Blender Render, as far as physics go.

Comment: @AnthonyForwood ok. I meant I'd rather use Cycles than the BGE.

Comment: I can walk you through this if you want to go to chat. I'm online all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the axle, then the wheel, and press Control+J to join them into one object.  Now the axle and wheel will move together.